# In general, is $(nZ, +)$ isomorphic to $(Z,+)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In general, is $(nZ, +)$ isomorphic to $(Z,+)$?

I believe that it is.

Let $f: Z \to nZ$ be $f(x)=nx$

This function is bijective since you can find $f^{-1}(x)= \frac{x}{n}$

Now we have to show that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$

$f(a+b) = n(a+b) = na + nb = f(a) + f(b)$

Does this make sense? I'm not sure if I'm proving it right.

Comment: Well, $n$ might not be 2, but yes (when $n$ is anything but 0).  (Also, they are both infinite cyclic, so they are iso.)

Comment: @Randall yes that was my mistake, I meant for it to be n.

Comment: See [here](https://www.quora.com/Prove-that-Z-and-nZ-are-isomorphic-for-any-nonzero-integer-n-How-would-you-do-it).

Answer (score 1):

This (almost) proves that $(n\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ are isomorphic as groups, yes. You should probably be more explicit about why $f$ is bijective, namely, how do we know that $\frac{x}{n}$ is actually an integer? If you know group theory, you could also simply say that $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are infinite cyclic groups, and all infinite cyclic groups are isomorphic.

It's worth noting though that they are not isomorphic as rings though, as $\mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplicative identity element while $n\mathbb{Z}$ does not.

Comment: You may want to add that $n \mathbb Z$ is not a ring when viewed as a substructure of the natural ring structure on $\mathbb Z$. Otherwise we could just push forward the ring structure on $\mathbb Z$ to its isomorphic group on $n \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @StefanMesken It depends how you define "ring" - some texts don't demand a multiplicative unit (although my understanding is that this is extremely rare).

Comment: @NoahSchweber At the very least, Dummit and Foote draws a distinction between general rings and rings with identity.